# ODAC 12c release 1 compatibility

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle12c

I am starting a project which will use Oracle 10g release 2 as database and Visual Studio 2012 for development. I would like to ask if the ODAC 12c release 1 would work in that scenario.

Also the development environment I will be using an Oracle 11g XE but the final product will connect to an Oracle 10g release 2 database.

Is it possible to use the ODAC 12c for both scenarios or would I have to work with ODAC 10g release 2? If this is the case, which versions of Windows are compatible with ODAC 10g r2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you'll be fine with 10gR2.  From the [install docs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/install121010-1979179.html)

> ## System Requirements
>
> The following items are required for ODAC:
>
> ```
> Windows operating system
>     32-bit: Windows 8 (Pro and Enterprise editions), Windows 7 (Professional, Enterprise, Ultimate editions), Windows Server 2008
>     x64: Windows 8 (Pro and Enterprise editions), Windows 7 (Professional, Enterprise, Ultimate editions), Windows Server 2012
> ```
>
> (Standard, Datacenter, Essentials, and Foundation Editions), Windows
>   Server 2008 R2 and Windows Server 2008 (all editions, except HPC)
>       **Access to an Oracle Database Server (Oracle 10g Release 2 or later)**
>   Additional Notes on Requirements:

```
ODP.NET requires Microsoft .NET Framework.
    ODP.NET, Managed Driver requires .NET Framework 4 or later up to .NET Framework 4.5
    ODP.NET, Unmanaged Driver requires .NET Framework 3.5 SP 1 or later up to .NET Framework 4.5
Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio requires Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 or Visual Studio 2012.

Note: Visual Studio Express Editions are not supported with the Oracle Developer Tools. However, ODP.NET is supported with Visual Studio Express Edition.
```